# Profile is not getting executed when running SUDO in AIX 6.1?

Tags: linux, sudo, aix, sudoers

In user1 , the ~/.profile is set to have the LIBPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LIBPATH
as user2, I am running

sudo -u user1 /usr/bin/sqlplus

it complains that libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

for some reason that profile is not executed to set the LIBPATH when running using sudo -u in AIX.

But i think in linux there is sudo -i -u user1 to execute the profile, but what how can it be done the same in AIX or any ideas to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

AIX uses LIBPATH not LD_LIBRARY_PATH to search for libraries

Comment: Even after changing to LIBPATH it still doesn't include the profile and finding the libraries when executing sudo , any help ?